# CMake + CUDA + separable compilation -> "nvcc doesn't know what to do with ' ' "

Tags: cmake, cuda, nvcc, compiler-flags

I use CMake for a project of mine involving CUDA. Recently I have had to turn on  "separable compilation" of the some of my CUDA code:

```
set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

but then, building started to fail. As an example, the following would happen:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -gencode arch=compute_30,code=compute_30 --std=c++11 \
   -Xcompiler -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG "" "" "" "" -m64 -ccbin /usr/bin/cc \
   -dlink /some/where/generated_foo.cu.o -o /some/where/foo_intermediate_link.o
nvcc fatal   : Don't know what to do with ''
```

(lines broken and names shortened for readability)

So, the problem is that something triggers CMake to add some empty (quoted) strings to the command-line, which nvcc doesn't like. Other than that the command seems fine.

Now, `-O3 -DNDEBUG` are my nvcc compilation flags for release builds. But I've certainly not added any empty-string flags anywhere. I tried looking into how FindCUDA constructs the nvcc invocation, but couldn't quite figure out where these empty strings are coming.

Without going into the specifics of my `CMakeLists.txt`, could this possibly be a well-known issue with CMake's FindaCUDA module which has a general workaround?

Note: I use GNU/Linux Mint 18.3, CMake 3.5, and CUDA 9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this *is* a known [CMake issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16411).

The workaround is to only set build-config-specific compilation flags for the active build config, e.g. instead of having:

```
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O3)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_DEBUG ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g --generate-line-info)
```

in your `CMakeLists.txt`, use:

```
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UPPER STREQUAL "RELEASE")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O3)
elseif (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UPPER STREQUAL "DEBUG")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_DEBUG ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g --generate-line-info)
endif (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UPPER STREQUAL "RELEASE")
```

instead (or more cases if you have multiple build types).

Another possible alternative is to not use FindCUDA at all, as CMake has added support for CUDA as a "first-class" language beginning with some 3.X release (not sure what X is).